# Non-synthesizable clocking style: only conditional operations or if statements are supported in sync-async always blocks

Tags: system-verilog, case-statement

I am trying SV code which involves both using `priority` and `casez` constructs together.  What I want to achieve is based on the valid request available (`sel` is a 4-bit register which will contain who has valid request at a time).  An output will be generated based on the least significant bit who has valid request.

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) 
begin 
Priority casez(sel) 
4'b0000: check = 4'b0;
4'b???1: check = 4'b1;
4'b??1?: check = 4'b2;
4'b?1??: check = 4'b4;
4'b1???: check = 4'b8;
default: check = 4'b0;
endcase
end
```

When I try to execute this code through emulation, I am facing an issue which states:

> Non-synthesizable clocking style: only conditional operations or if
> statements are supported in sync-async always blocks

Does this mean that `priority` `casez` can't be synthesized?
If it's not possible, what's the best way to achieve this without defining each and every possible combination of `sel`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `rst` in the sensitivity list, you must also use it in the body of the `always` block.  For example, if you want an asynchronous reset, you would add an `if/else` statement:

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (!rst) begin
        check <= 4'd0;
    else begin
        priority casez (sel) 
            4'b0000: check <= 4'd0;
            4'b???1: check <= 4'd1;
            4'b??1?: check <= 4'd2;
            4'b?1??: check <= 4'd4;
            4'b1???: check <= 4'd8;
            default: check <= 4'd0;
        endcase
    end
end
```

I corrected some syntax errors.  The `priority` keyword must be lower case.  It is illegal to use the `'b` base specifier with numbers like 2, 4 and 8.  I changed the specifier to `'d`.

Also, good coding practices recommend using nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for sequential logic.